# MS Excel OFFSET height not correct

Tags: excel, excel-formula, height, offset

I use `OFFSET` to create dynamic range names, very often.  Normally I use a formula for the height and my columns are fixed. This time I have fixed height and a formula for my columns.

The formula returns 3 rows only, and the correct number of columns.  I have tried both of the following formulas, the first one `COUNTA` is sort of silly, as it is 16, like the second one, but I thought it would make Excel happy if I did that. It does not. I get the first three rows and all columns, just like the second formula.

```vb
=OFFSET(Inputs!$D$57,0,0,COUNTA(Inputs!$D$57:$D72),COUNTA(Inputs!$57:$57))
=OFFSET(Inputs!$D$57,0,0,16,COUNTA(Inputs!$57:$57))
```

There is data in all rows of the first column, numbers, and text, but every row has a value.  The same with row 57, every column has a value.

Here is a depiction of the first three columns, not going to post all 100+ columns.

[image]

And this is what it returns...

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Only if every cell in D57:D72 has a value in it is COUNTA() the same as 16.

Comment: So what do you expect it to return?

Comment: It returns 16 rows, 3 columns if I reproduce.

Comment: That is what is baffling me.  It is returning 3 rows, and the 141 columns that it should.  I just put the 3 columns in there as the 141 is too much.  And yes, the "Code" is column D, my bad for not being clear on that.  So there is data on each row.  I just can't understand why it stops on the 3rd row.  Maybe my workbook is corrupt or something.  So odd.